# SQL Query: difference in condition in On clause and where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, where-clause

I am trying to get the difference between below 2 queries

**Query 1:**

In which I have given condition **'Orders.OrderID != null'** in on clause

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON (Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID and Orders.OrderID is not null)
```

**Query 2:**

In which I have given condition **'Orders.OrderID != null'** in where clause

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID where Orders.OrderID is not null
```

These 2 queries are generating difference results. Why?
*What is the execution flow for where clause and on condition clause?*

P.S I am using the following link for testing of the queries http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join

Comment: `OrderID != null` is never correct, regardless of where you put it. The correct way to test against `null`s would be `OrderID IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: I am using the following link to test the query.. where above mentioned query is working fine.. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join

Comment: in both flavors (condition in the `on` and the `where` clauses), `OrderID != null` returns 0 rows, while `OrderID IS NOT NULL` returns 196 rows. How can it the query be "working fine"?

Comment: Something wrong with your design here, how do you get an order in Orders with a null ID, but it does have a customerID, that would worry me, a lot..

Comment: This website has a related examples: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231132/Difference-between-And-clause-along-with-on-and-Wh Cases 2 & 3 pertain to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference in that in query 1, Orders.OrderID != null (or Orders.OrderId is not null) is being used to filter the rows in the Orders table and in query2, it is being used to filter the rows in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `!= NULL` to `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: i am change the sql and tried at link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join still getting the different result... kindly explain

Comment: any ways is not null in main question

Answer (score 0):

Change the `!= NULL` to `IS NOT NULL` and **do not** forget to place parentheses at `ON` clause.

This way you tell the server that you want all conditions (inside parentheses) to be met when joining.

Answer (score 0):

The Q2 in fact it the same as `INNER JOIN Orders`.

The rows without peer are filtered out.

UPDATE

for the Q1 if the condition is false the row from Customers is included in results.
for the Q2 the left joined rows are filtered out because hteir OrderId is null

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your queries look similar to T-Sql, except the comparison "!=". If you are using MSSQL Server, the proper way to test null values is `OrderId is not null`.

Besides the uses of different operators, the behaviors of your queries are also driven by order of processing. The WHERE clause conditions are evaluated upon the results of all JOIN's. This is true for MSSQL. Because of that, putting conditions in WHERE clause has similar effects as if you do an INNER JOIN, except that you are wasting more resources.

Comment: so why in case of left join.. null values are not getting filtered ?

Comment: @dhroove in the first query? Because it's a join condition. An left outer join will give you **all** rows of the first table combined with those rows of the second table that fulfill the join condition - if there isn't one the selected fields from the second table will be null. That's a huge difference to filtering with `WHERE`.

Comment: @dhroove JOIN conditions are for matching, not filtering. VMai is correct that LEFT JOIN takes precedence over matching conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that first query will output all rows from first table and only those rows from second table which match condition. That means that columns that belong to second table will be `null`, but combined row would still exist in result.

In second case combined rows which have order ID `null` will be removed.